# react-native audio sending issue

Tags: file, react-native

I am trying to send an audio file but I think I am not selecting the file correctly.
I am using react-native-audio-toolkit and I was trying to use the rec object where it records, but that does not seem to work, how could I get the file to send it?
code:

```
let rec = new Recorder("filename.mp4").record();

// Stop recording after approximately 3 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  rec.stop(err => {
    // NOTE: In a real situation, handle possible errors here
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("recording[path_to_recording]", rec);
    data.append("recording[challenge_id]", 1);
    data.append("recording[user_id]", 1);
    console.log(data);
    axios
      .post(config.API_URL + "recordings", data, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.props.auth.token
        }
      })
      .then(res => res.data);
```

the log of the recording file looks like this:

> Recorder {_path: "filename.mp4", _options: {…}, _recorderId: 0, _state: -2, _duration: -1, …}
>   _duration
>   :
>   -1
>   _fsPath
>   :
>   "/data/user/0/com.cobrn/files/filename.mp4"
>   _lastSync
>   :
>   -1
>   _options
>   :
>   autoDestroy
>   :
>   (...)
>   get autoDestroy
>   :
>   ƒ ()
>   set autoDestroy
>   :
>   ƒ ()
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Object
>   _path
>   :
>   "filename.mp4"
>   _position
>   :
>   -1
>   _recorderId
>   :
>   0
>   _state
>   :
>   -2
>   canPrepare
>   :
>   (...)
>   canRecord
>   :
>   (...)
>   fsPath
>   :
>   (...)
>   isPrepared
>   :
>   (...)
>   isRecording
>   :
>   (...)
>   state
>   :
>   (...)
>   **proto**
>   :
>   EventEmitter

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, you need the specify the type

```
data.append("recording[path_to_recording]", {
      uri: "file://" + rec._fsPath,
      name: "filename.mp4",
      type: "audio/mp4"
    });
```